# LVM to EXT2 conversion

Tags: centos7, lvm, conversion

I have just installed a new version of Centos 7.
I had an empty drive which I partition how I wanted to but could not get the install dialog to accept.  In the end I said to use its defaults.

Now I have a LVM partition with CENTOS7.4.
I want to convert this is a EXT2 partition does any one know how to do this - without having to go through the hassle of re-installing

(Yes I know there are going to be people who know better and wish to tell me  the error of my ways that EXT2 is bad and that EXT3 or EXT4 are much better.  And that LVM being logical volumes are hardware independent.  Can I request you ignore said impulses and accept that as IT person with over 20 years experience I find that for my home systems EXT2 is by the far the simplest and easiest to maintain)

Comment: Can you post the output of some partition tool (`fdisk -lu /dev/sdxxx`) and of `pvs`, `vgs` and `lvs`?

Answer (score 0):

cfdisk, or most other disk partition managers, will easily do this for you. Then use mkfs.ext2 to create the ext2 file system there. Of course that will destroy any data that were in the partition.

You can convert between ext2, ext3, and ext4 at any time using tune2fs.